# Двухязычный статичный сайт без CMS

Tags: php, html

Господа, нужен Ваш совет, решение, etc.
Есть сайт простой сайт, без админки, просто набор страниц (штук 20), контент на укр. языке, нужно сделать его рос. версию, чтобы получилось типа: site.com.ua\index.php - на укр. языке и site.com.ua\ru\index.php на рос. языке.  
**Сделано**: в корневой папке сайта созданы две папки \ua i \ru в каждой их них есть полностью готовый сайт на соответствующем языке со всеми страницами, картинками и т.д. 
**Вопрос**: как объединить эти две версии? Нужно ли создать какой-то файл типа index.php в корневой папке сайта и там прописать чтоб при запросе в поисковике сайт выводился на соответствующем языке запроса и чтоб была дефолтная версия? Как это сделать? 
**И вопрос номер два**: что прописать для переключения текущей страницы между языками.

Comment: а почему на /ru сайте не кинуть линк на /ua сайт и наоборот?? ну сделайте комбобокс как на вп, например. флажки там выпали, выбрали нужный.

Answer (score 2):

Не нужно никакой "общей версии" - это прошлый век. Пользователь должен войти на сайт и сразу получить контент. Редиректите всех зашедших "не туда" с помощью [`.htaccess`](http://www.seoschool.ru/search-engine-optimization-seo/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide.html). Например, всех по умолчанию шлем сразу на украинскую версию:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^(ru/|ua/).* http://site.com/ua/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Так вы и ссылки в поисковых системах и на других сайтах не потеряете.

Что на счет перехода между версиями - сделайте на страницу ссылку на версию с противоположным языком. Она может быть текстовой (RU/UA) или в виде картинки с флажком.

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ. но я не совсем понял, что значит общая версия? ведь я создал две разноязычные версии одного сайта. На счет перехода между страницами понял, спасибо большое!!!

Comment: Допустим, у вас была страница `site.ua/goodpage`. Если вы переместили ее на `site.ua/ua/goodpage`, то люди, которые переходят с другого сайта по старой ссылке увидят `404`. Чтобы этого не случилось, я предлагаю переадресовать их на новую ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

Можете проверять язык браузера в .htaccess вот так:

```
#ru
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (ru) [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://greatestsiteever.com/ru/ [R=302,L]
#ua
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://greatestsiteever.com/ua/ [R=302,L]
```

Юзер будет перенаправлен в папку с локализацией, соответствующей языку браузера пользователя.